# Ruby on Rails 3 CSS only for certain Views (Devise)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, asset-pipeline

I am quite new to Ruby on Rails and wanted to place my custom CSS file into the Devise (Sign Up View). I placed my global CSS into the application.js (Asset Pipeline) and placed 2 Helper functions in my

**helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
  def javascript(*files)
    content_for(:head_javascript) { javascript_include_tag(*files) }
  end

  def stylesheet(*files)
    content_for(:head_stylesheet) { stylesheet_link_tag(*files) }
  end
```

and my **views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
   if (controller.controller_name == "sessions") && (controller.action_name == "new")
     javascript 'theme/signup'
     stylesheet 'theme/signup'
   end
%>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Mysite</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <%= yield(:head_stylesheet) %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application",  :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= yield(:head_javascript) %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I generated the Devise Views and adjusted my twitter bootstrap form
 `rails generate devise:views`

And now want to place my **signup.css** inside the Signup View, but how?

So I created the Devise Controllers, to use my helper methods:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/foohey/cdc/master/cdc.sh)
```

Now I am stuck, because I my helpers don´t work with:

```
<%
   if (controller.controller_name == "sessions") && (controller.action_name == "new")
     javascript 'theme/signup'
     stylesheet 'theme/signup'
   end
%>
```

Is there an easy way in rails to handle custom css files? I am new to the asset pipeline concept and it is a bit confusing.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard about content_for? It is really useful for things like that. Inside you layout add:

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

inside your head tag. Then you can write the following inside the view (devise/sessions/new):

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  javascript 'theme/signup'
  stylesheet 'theme/signup'
<% end %>
```

This will perfectly separate your layout from single view concerns, and it should also fix the problem you're having.

Comment: Is it possible to declare this in the <body> tag of my view?

Comment: @zer02, you can declare it wherever you want. 'yield :some_symbol' inside layout will 'paste' whatever has been passed to 'content_for :some_symbol'. Content_for simply saves the block it is being passed for later use in layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your custom css files in the css directory inside the public directory and inside the `<head>` tags of the view you want the custom css files to be you do this

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/css/signup' %>`

The `signup.css` will only be available to the signup view assuming that's where you place your stylesheet_link_tag

Comment: The view does not have a <head> section. Do I need to set serve static files in the config for development environment? Not finding the css in /public/stylesheets

Comment: css was just an example, just create a directory and name it css or whatever name you wish. if there are no head tags on your `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` just write your own `<head></head>` on top of the page and place the `stylesheet_link_tag` there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like these:--

```
<% if (controller.controller_name == "sessions") && (controller.action_name == "new")%>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "theme/signup"%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "theme/signup" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I did this, but I dont know what controller action is triggered in devise, when going to sign up. The routes file don´t show if it is sessions new. The controller exists, but the functions are empty and uncommented. So I am actually looking for a solution NOT to use this.

Comment: better you can directly use you `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` into the view by overriding them from devise file rather than in layout

Comment: The sign up process is triggered by the `new` action of the `registrations_controller.rb`. The controller should therefore be `registrations` and not `sessions`